# Postfix mail server issue

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I get this error in postfix mail.log

```
postfix/error[2537]: 3C1E26FB3A: to=<root@ar.net>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=9.3, delays=9.3/0/0/0, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: host mailgot.xo.com[192.13.11.78] refused to talk to me: 550 Too many invalid recipients)
```

and the result of ps aux | grep postfix are  error -n retry -t unix -u.

Answer (score 0):

Put this to google: `refused to talk to me: 550 Too many invalid recipients`.

If you send to many messages to unknown mailboxes, mail server can blacklist your IP... Grep your log for `mailgot.xo.com` to see what was sent.